# Cannot find 'javaxt-core' on Maven Repo

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have added the dependency below to my pom.xml but Eclipse (Oxygen) keeps giving the following error **Missing artifact javaxt:javaxt-core:jar:1.7.8**. Is there a way around this?

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javaxt/javaxt-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javaxt</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaxt-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Is Eclipse configured to work Offline with Maven?

Comment: No it isn't, but some @bhargav-modi answer worked this time around

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually found a more stable way of fixing this issue as the previously accepted answer did not work on other environments. I had to add the below to my pom.xml:

```
   <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>jspresso-repository</id>
                <url>http://repository.jspresso.org/maven2</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
   </repositories>
```

Comment: I added Maven support to the JavaXT website which will be more up-to-date then jspresso. More info [here](http://javaxt.com/downloads).

Comment: @Peter: Trying to use the javaxt maven repo - but getting an "invalid sha1" error.  Working in Eclipse/ivy - the native Eclipse ivy resolver can resolve the jar, but ant/ivy is throwing the error.

Comment: @jomofrodo I would love to help. Can you shoot me an email? My contact info is on javaxt.com

Comment: jspresso is fully offline, predictably.

Answer (score 4):

I recently added Maven support to the JavaXT website. Please use the following "repository" in your pox.xml:

```
<repositories>
   <repository>
     <id>javaxt.com</id>
     <url>http://www.javaxt.com/maven</url>
   </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: Sorry, but not gonna use something that's not in maven central. Not going to force me to clean up after the project dies. And most of them do, eventually.

Comment: @user1050755 I haven't been pushing any releases to Maven Central or any site other than javaxt.com so the releases there may be out of sync with the official repo on javaxt.com

Comment: How come you don't push to maven central?

Answer (score 0):

Try few things out like below

1. **Project > clean**
2. right click on project and move on **Maven > Update Project Configuration**
3. Disable then re-enable dependency management
4. Lastly if any of above doesn't work then delete .m2 hidden folder or rename it and let maven create another .m2 directory.

Comment: I have been doing this for some time before asking the question and some how it worked in that order